# Excel VBA function not working for Class

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function that is suppose to call its self for performing a summation.  But when it gets to the line it pops up a window wanting a Macro.  Does VBA not support this or am I missing something?

```
Sub SumUp(ByVal result As Double, ByVal number As Integer)

sumValue As Double
numValue As Integer

numValue = number

If (number > 0) Then

    sumValue = numValue * 2
    numValue = numValue - 1
    SumUp(result = sumValue, number = numValue)

Else
    MsgBox numValue
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Technically it's not a function because it doesn't return any value, so the call SumUp(result = sumValue, number = numValue) is wrong

2.) You are missing Dim statements

-->

```
Sub SumUp(ByVal result As Double, ByVal number As Integer)

Debug.Print "result=" & result & ", number=" & number

Dim sumValue As Double
Dim numValue As Integer

numValue = number

If (number > 0) Then

    sumValue = numValue * 2
    numValue = numValue - 1


    SumUp sumValue, numValue

Else
    MsgBox numValue
End If

End Sub
```

Executing

```
Sub testit()
SumUp 2, 2
End Sub
```

delivers the following output:

```
result=2, number=2
result=4, number=1
result=2, number=0
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SumUp(result = sumValue, number = numValue)
> ```

This is invalid on many levels.

If you meant to call `SumUp` with named parameters, you should have written

```
SumUp result:= sumValue, number:= numValue
```

You don't have to use named parameters though:

```
SumUp sumValue, numValue
```